# Zapier not grabbing the Extra Requested Fields from token response

Tags: auth0, zapier

I am basically trying to create a Zapier App for an application.
The application Authentication takes place via Auth0 and in that I am setting extra values in AccessToken and IdToken in the token response from Auth0. I can confirm that Auth0 is indeed setting the values and passing the same in the callback URL.

Technically in Zapier Authentication Settings there is an advanced feature where we can provide a Comma separated list of extra items to grab from a token response. access_token and refresh_token are already grabbed for you.

So having done the configuration as per the documents Zapier doesn't seem to be passing the values.

Comment: are you writing a cli app or a web builder app?

Comment: @xavdid web builder app